# Watch/Subscribe if certain action has occurred in store

Tags: typescript, vue.js, pinia

How do you watch or subscribe to an action occurring in a store?

I tried adding a watch (see below) however this doesn't work.

`setShowModal` is the action I want to watch/subscribe to in my component)

Component:

```
<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from 'vue'
import { store } from '@/stores/store'

export default defineComponent({
    data () {
        return {
            showModal: store().showModal
        }
    },
    watch: {
        showModal(oldValue, newValue) {
            if (newValue) {
                this.getComments()
            }
        }
    },
```

Store:

```
state: () => {
    return {
      showModal: false
    }
},
actions: {
  setShowModal(val: boolean) {
    this.showModal = val
  }
}
```

The only way I have gotten the watch to fire (only when value gets changed to false) is if I write my component like this:

```
<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from 'vue'
import {store} from '@/stores/store'

export default defineComponent({
    data () {
        return {
            store: store()
        }
    },
    watch: {
        'store.showModal': function(newValue) {
            if (newValue) {
                this.getComments()
            }
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 5):

#### [How to get reactive state from Pinia store in Vue2.](https://pinia.vuejs.org/core-concepts/state.html#without-setup)

```
import { mapState } from 'pinia'
import {store} from '@/stores/store'

export default {
  computed: {
    // gives access to this.showModal inside the component
    // which you can then watch
    ...mapState(store, ['showModal '])
  },

  watch: {
    showModal(newVal) {
      this.getComments();
    }
  },
}
```

Worth noting that state mapped in this way is **readonly**. Read the docs further if you want the **writable** state (which in this case, you do not want).

Answer (score 0):

```
data () {
    return {
        store: store()
    }
},
watch: {
    'store.showModal': function(newValue) {
        if (newValue) {
            this.getComments()
        }
    }
},
```

Comment: I am using typescript and this does not work

Comment: I changed the answer and it's what you alredy tried. does it not work?

Comment: this only fires when the value is set to false, not sure why it doesn't also fire when the value is changed to true

Comment: You do not need the `if (newValue)` if you wish to get comments on every action call. Although I donot understand why you would watch the action, when the action is changing the store value. Just watch the `showModal` state from the store.